For loop doesn't refresh name in the UI
In Android (Kotlin), I am doing a for loop to solve the problem of finding an exact word and I want to show the words calculated and the iteration number in a TextView, but the word and numbers are only showed once the for loop has finished and not over the calculation.
private fun buscaPaco(){

    for (i in 1..1000000) {
        tamañoABC = abc.size - 1
        ordenLetra01 = (0..tamañoABC).random()
        ordenLetra02 = (0..tamañoABC).random()
        ordenLetra03 = (0..tamañoABC).random()
        ordenLetra04 = (0..tamañoABC).random()
        abcLetra01 = abc[ordenLetra01]
        abcLetra02 = abc[ordenLetra02]
        abcLetra03 = abc[ordenLetra03]
        abcLetra04 = abc[ordenLetra04]

        palabra02 = abcLetra01 + abcLetra02 + abcLetra03 + abcLetra04
        tvPalabras.text = palabra02

        if (palabra01 == palabra02){
            tvEncontrado.text = palabra01 + " encontrado. Iteración: " + i.toString()
            tvEncontrado.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red)
            break
        }
        else{
            tvEncontrado.text = "buscando, iteración: " + i.toString()
        }

        factor1To100 = i/factor100
        factorInt = factor1To100.toInt()
        escribirProgreso()

    }

}


I have zero knowledge on programming Android, but this sounds like you're doing it on the UI thread, which means updates to the UI are blocked until your loop finishes. You need to perform your operations off the UI thread.

I don't know how to do it. My function is inside the button listener, where i would need to put it? Thank you in advance

It might happen quickly that you don't see any intermediate steps. As far as I understand, you only see the final result? You can try adding text rather than replacing it if you wanna see intermediate results. Not sure what your code is supposed to really be doing because it's in Spanish, and my Spanish sucks :D

Please explain what you are trying to achieve, because running the for loop as it is, is not a good practice.

Its not recommended to use large loop. Use thread/coroutines to solve this issue.
Thread {
//all your code
tvPalabras.post {
tvPalabras.text = palabra02
}
}.start()

You are doing calculations (heavy task) on the Main UI thread. So it freezes the UI until your loop finished. To solve this problem, you can do calculations in the background and update results on the main UI thread. You can use Thread, Kotlin coroutines or Java concurrent for that.
Here is an example of using coroutines.
private fun buscaPaco() {
    val job = lifecycleScope.launch {
        for (i in 1..1000000) {
            // do some calculations in the background ..
            palabra02 = ...

            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                // update UI in Main thread
                tvPalabras.text = palabra02
                // ...
                escribirProgreso() // also update progress in Main thread
            }

            // ...
            // You can also set delay between each calculations using delay()
            delay(100)
        }
    }

    // you can cancel the job at any time using job.cancel()
}


it works perfectly but is updating all the UI, the launch(Dispatchers.Main) {} is not necessary. Now the App looks great, thank you for your awesome answer. I am going to figure out more about this lifecycleScope.launch
